# How to write query with in a query using LINQ by passing a list

Tags: sql, linq

```
select * from emp where employeeno in
(
      select b.emp_ID from employee c 
      inner join employee1 b on b.emp_ID=c.emp_Id 
      where ename='scott' and sal=1000)
)
```

By passing a list of Employee ID's and iterating

Comment: You have tagged question with *linq* tag, but forgot to add any linq queries to it. Please update question

Comment: var result = from e1 in db1.emp
                             where e1.eno in 
                             (from db in db1.employee
                               join obj in db1.emploeyee1 on db.emp_ID equals obj.emp_ID
                               where db.ename == 'scott' && db.sal == 1000
                                 select db.emp_ID)
                             select e1;

Comment: This is what I have written in LINQ actually in subquery it returns a list of Employee id by that it has to iterate and show me the result

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Contains` in LINQ to get an `IN` in SQL.

I.e. the SQL:

```
IN (id1, id2, id3, id4)
```

would be a

```
MyListOfIds.Contains(MyTable.Id)
```

in the LINQ side, where `MyListOfIds` contains id1, id2, id3, id4. This is translated as the neede IN predicate in the SQL side.